# Combining GitHub and TFS / Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, github, team-foundation-server

I wonder if it's possible to combine Visual Studio Team Services and/or TFS with a GitHub repository. We think both products have their own advantages and would like to work on one repo within our company.

The reason to use VSTS / TFS is the integration in Visual Studio for Work Items.

Comment: Have you tried the plugin? https://visualstudio.github.com/

Comment: What do you perceive you're getting from github that you're not from VSTS and git ? Assuming git across the board using both is not really a huge issue apart from discussions of how to keep it all neatly synchronised.

Comment: Old question, new answer:
Since [Microsoft purchased GitHub](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/04/technology/microsoft-github-cloud-computing.html), using Visual Studio with a git repo is a reality. Directions on getting started with Git and VSTS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/gitquickstart?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Elsa that’s not since MS bought github. VSTS has supported Git for years. Also, re the OP, if you’re using VSTS for work items, there’s no real reason to pay for Github too. Github’s big difference from VSTS is how it handles issue tracking.

Comment: I've been using github with Visual Studio for years now...I'm not sure what you are asking OP, it is exceedingly easy to set this up.

Comment: What do you mean by support? Vsts can build from GitHub repos. What else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be the successor to TFS, now known as Azure DevOps. This solution is essentially the same TFS that you have grown to know and "love", while adding the option to use GitHub, a Git Repository that is private to your organization, or VSTS as your code repository, while still tracking the work items, builds, code changes, and being able to tie them all together, in much the same way that you already do. The latest version also has Markdown support, and the ability to build your change management plan by simply linking the work items, bugs and code changes together under a given User Story, even in a hybrid environment, where some stuff is in the cloud, but there's other stuff that get's kept inside the company firewall.

There's so much more than would do the solution justice here. Go check out [Microsoft Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/?nav=min), and see for yourself just how versatile it is!

Answer (score 0):

As you have not written much about what your aim is to achieve from both i have used them to get these benefits.

TFS:

- Was already integrated into client other developments and staff was comfortable managing it so kept requirements and work items there.
- Backlog is built with in this and tracking of work items is performed here.

GITHUB:

- A placeholder repo to keep bug and issues on existing releases
- Customer has multiple branches and can raise a request from anywhere in the world using email that creates a github issue and label it accordingly.
- Slight automation and assignment for keeping things under SLAs

The problem in using both is that you are splitting up the code flow and issue/requirement flow. For my project I realised that requirements are more tightly bound to code changes while issues may likely be around documentation, lack of training etc so I used github features to tackle customer side of things while actual product development was kept on TFS.

Both github and TFS can achieve this on its own so no point in mixing them if you dont need to.